# iOS 7 tintColor does not apply to controls

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uitableview, uibutton

I have faced a strange behaviour of iOS 7 on iPad. My issue can be described with one image:

[image]

- running controller on iPad results in grey buttons (not correct behaviour)
- running controller on iPhone results in blue buttons (correct behaviour)
- buttons, views and window have default colours (never changed in code)
- using XIBs, not storyboards
- manual setting [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.tintColor or app delegate's window.tintColor does not work.

Any ideas why it behaves like this?